# ruby reorder array of symbols in one pass

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I am looking for the most efficient way to do this. Anything with a hyphen must be in before any symbols without a hyphen in the array. My naive solution filters the array twice and concats. I feel like there should be a way to do this in one pass instead of two.

```
input = [:en, :de, :es, :"es-MX", :fr, :ko, :"ko-KR", :"en-GB"]

output = [:"es-MX", :"ko-KR", :"en-GB", :en, :de, :es, :fr]
```

Naive solution:

```
def reorder(input)
  ## find everything with a hypen
  output = input.select { |l| 
    l.to_s.include?('-')
  }

  # find everything without a hyphen and concat to output
  output.concat(input.reject { |l| 
    l.to_s.include?('-')
  })
end
```

Comment: If there is no restriction on the order of the symbols with and without hyphens you can write the following: `[:en, :de, :es, :"es-MX", :fr, :ko, :"ko-KR", :"en-GB"].each_with_object([]) { |sym, arr| sym.to_s.include?('-') ? arr.unshift(sym) : arr << sym } #=>  [:"en-GB", :"ko-KR", :"es-MX", :en, :de, :es, :fr, :ko]`. I see this is a variant of @Balastrong's answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a sorting task, so it makes the most sense to me to simply use `Enumerable#sort_by`:

```rb
# Put symbols with hyphens first
input.sort_by { |s| s.to_s.include?('-') ? 0 : 1 }
```

If you want to sort by something else within those categories, you can do something like this:

```rb
# Put symbols with hyphens first, then sort in alphabetical order
input.sort_by { |s| [s.to_s.include?('-') ? 0 : 1, s] }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the array in one pass with Array#partition:

```
def reorder(input)
  a, b = input.partition { |l| l.to_s.include?('-') }

  a.concat(b)
end
```

Comment: I believe this is the only answer so far that meets the single-pass requirement and also is order-preserving among symbols containing a hyphen and among symbols that do not contain a hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

```
input = [:en, :de, :es, :"es-MX", :fr, :ko, :"ko-KR", :"en-GB"]
```

code

```
p input.partition{|x|x.to_s.include?'-'}.flatten
```

Output

```
[:"es-MX", :"ko-KR", :"en-GB", :en, :de, :es, :fr, :ko]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it in two passes as I can see.

With one pass only, you could add an `if` statement and check each element then push it on the `left` array if it contains the hypen, on the `right` array otherwise.

Then concat the arrays.

```rb
def reorder(input)
  left = []
  right = []
  input.each { |l| 
    if l.to_s.include?('-')
      left.push(l)
    else
      right.push(l)
    end
  }

  left.concat(right)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that makes a single pass through the array and preserves the ordering of symbols with hyphens and the ordering of symbols without hyphens.

```
def rearrange(arr)
  a = arr.dup
  pos = -1
  a.size.times { |i| a.insert(pos+=1, a.delete_at(i)) if a[i].to_s.include?('-') }
  a
end
```

```
rearrange [:en, :de, :es, :"es-MX", :fr, :ko, :"ko-KR", :"en-GB"]
  #=> [:"es-MX", :"ko-KR", :"en-GB", :en, :de, :es, :fr, :ko]
```

The the use of [Kernel#dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) (to avoid mutating the original array) does not constitute a pass through the array because (as I understand) the C code copies blocks of memory.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
input.sort do |a,b|
  next a <=> b if a.to_s.include?('-') == b.to_s.include?('-')
  a.to_s.include?('-') ? -1 : 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def sort(arr)
  with_hyphen = []
  without_hyphen = []
  for item in arr do
    if item.include?("-")
       with_hyphen << item
    else
       without_hyphen << item
    end
  end
  return with_hyphen + without_hyphen
end
```